# Make 2 Sails Applications Communicate

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sails.js, web-development-server

I have a sailsjs project that has a member portal. It includes all possible routes/actions. However, I'm thinking of making a cms using sails as well. Originally, I plan to just include it in the same project but I feel like, I shouldn't be doing it. So, I decided to make another sails project just for the CMS. Now, I want to be able to use the routes/actions I made in my first sails project. Is it possible for 2 sails project to talk to each other and do what I want? If yes, how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to edit the routes in CMS they should come from DB in the first place. Other than that what is the reason for the CMS to even know about the consumer routes/controllers/actions?

Comment: If you want to run both Sails Apps on the same VPS then run them on different ports and access them internally through localhost:portnumber make them communicate within themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if this is really possible, but, if we use the fact that the routes.js configuration is a key/value object, I think that you could simply put this object into a shared file in another place and then in the routes.js of each project you just refference the shared file, like follows:

```
//SharedRoutes.js
module.exports = {
    'get /path': 'Controller.action'
     ...
     ...
     ...
}
```

**Project 1**

```
Project1/config/routes.js

//LOAD THE SHARED ROUTES FROM THE SharedRoutes.js
var sharedObject = ...

// EXPORT IT NORMALLY AS BEING THE PROJECT 1 ROUTES...
module.exports.routes = sharedObject;
```

**Project 2**

```
Project2/config/routes.js

//LOAD THE SHARED ROUTES FROM THE SharedRoutes.js
var sharedObject = ...

// EXPORT IT NORMALLY AS BEING THE PROJECT 2 ROUTES...
module.exports.routes = sharedObject;
```

and if you want to have some local routes as well in one of your projects, you should simply merge the local routes object with the shared object, may be using `lodash library` (I think) or similar.

I do not tested it but it should work.

Hope it helps!